List all "Answers" on the first page
I want To make homework document that list all answers on the very first page. I had some issues explaining exaclty what im trying to do on Reddit so I thought this pusdo code would help explain.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

% Placeholder command to represent adding an answer (to be implemented)
\newcommand{\answer}[2]{This Is what I need help with!}

% Placeholder command for listing answers (to be implemented)
\newcommand{\listAnswers}{This too}

% Placeholder environment for a problem (to be implemented)
\newenvironment{Problem}[1]
  {I can figure this out on my own}
  {No need to help me here}

\begin{document}

\section{Quick Answers Reference}
% Notice that the function is called before the answers are called
\listAnswers
% Desired output
\[
    1.1)10 \\
    1.2)x^2 \\
    2.2)0 \\
]\

\begin{Problem}{1.1}
    \[
        5 + 5 = 
        % The answers are preferably called within a math environment.
        \answer{\questionnumber}{10} 
    \]
\end{Problem}

\begin{Problem}{1.2}
    \[
        x * x = 
        \answer{\questionnumber}{x^2} 
    \]
\end{Problem}

\begin{Problem}{2.2}
    \[
        0 + 0 = 
        \answer{\questionnumber}{0} 
    \]
\end{Problem}

\end{document}



this is not really clear enough to answer.  what you want is basically the same as a table of contents or list of tables which similarly lists at the start of a document, but you want to list just the answers without the problems, so the list just produces 10,3x,0  ?   with no context for what that means?

@DavidCarlisle, yeah, it just produces the answer, but with the question number so I guess a problem would look more like this:
\begin{Problem}{1.1}
    \[
        5 + 5 = 
        % The answers are preferably called within a math environment.
        \answer{\questionnumber}{10} % Pass the question number and the answer
    \]
\end{Problem}

The idea is the teacher can look at the front page and only check the work of problems with incorrect answers.
edit: Formatting

I suggest that you edit the example so that it produces the desired output (re-entering the data at the start) then it will be clear what you want and all anyone answering has to do is make the same output without copying the data by hand to the start,

@DavidCarlisle, Like that?

er... ! Missing $ inserted.

@DavidCarlisle I had that issue earlier and I think it has to do with the specific implantation of \listAnswers, because its talking the input from inside of the math env, and placing outside. so \listAnswers could give the environment or it can be added around the call.

@JohnKormylo you are correct, I was mistaken, I will fix it.

but you should still post an example that shows what it says it shows, you can not use \\  in \[ did you try it at all?

I expect to delete this later when somebody points out it will mean the death of butterflies or the end of strawberries.
This defines

\ListAnswers to print the list compiled during the previous run;
\answer[<label>]{<answer>} should be used within the problem environment, which needs to save the problem number so that the first argument is optional. If \answer is used in maths mode, <answer> will be wrapped appropriately, so the content should not be wrapped when given to \answer.


\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/723352/
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\seq_new:N \g_longtime_answers_seq
\seq_new:N \g_longtime_problems_seq
\tl_new:N \g__longtime_tmpa_tl
\cs_new:Npn \longtime_answer:nn #1#2
{
  \seq_gput_right:Ne \g_longtime_problems_seq {#1}
  \mode_if_math:TF
  {
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_longtime_answers_seq {$#2$}
  }{
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_longtime_answers_seq {#2}
  }
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \longtime_listing:nn #1#2
{
  \item[#1] #2
}
\hook_gput_code:nnn { enddocument  } { longtime }
{
  \tl_gset:Ne \g__longtime_tmpa_tl 
  {
    \seq_map_pairwise_function:NNN \g_longtime_problems_seq \g_longtime_answers_seq \longtimelistitem
  }
  \tl_gput_left:Nn \g__longtime_tmpa_tl {\begin{description}}
  \tl_gput_left:NV \g__longtime_tmpa_tl \c_left_brace_str
  \tl_gput_right:Nn \g__longtime_tmpa_tl {\end{description}}
  \tl_gput_right:NV \g__longtime_tmpa_tl \c_right_brace_str
  \tl_gput_left:Nn \g__longtime_tmpa_tl {\long\gdef\longtime@answers}
  \iow_now:NV \@auxout \g__longtime_tmpa_tl
}
\NewDocumentCommand \ListAnswers {}
{
  \cs_if_exist_use:N \longtime@answers
}
\NewDocumentCommand \answer { o +m }
{
  \IfValueTF { #1 } 
  {
    \longtime_answer:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  }{
    \longtime_answer:Vn \longtimeproblem { #2 }
  }
}
\cs_new_eq:NN \longtimelistitem \longtime_listing:nn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \longtime_answer:nn { Vn }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\listAnswers}{This too}

\newenvironment{Problem}[1]
{%
  \def\longtimeproblem{#1}%
  I can figure this out on my own}
  {No need to help me here}

\begin{document}

\section{Quick Answers Reference}
\ListAnswers

\begin{Problem}{1.1}
  \[
      5 + 5 = 
      \answer{10} 
  \]
\end{Problem}

\begin{Problem}{1.2}
  \[
      x * x = 
      \answer{x^2} 
  \]
\end{Problem}

\begin{Problem}{2.2}
  \[
  0 + 0 = 
  \answer{0} 
  \]
\end{Problem}

\begin{Problem}{2.3}
  \[
      0 + 0 = 
      \answer[3.X]{1,000} 
  \]
\end{Problem}

\end{document}


Wow thank you, I did not expect it to be so complicated.

@LongTime there may be a simpler solution. but you basically have to write the information to an external file and then read it back on the next run. it isn't possible for TeX to produce the list directly from the source because it reads the input sequentially and you want the list to come before the stuff-to-be-listed. so either use an existing file or a dedicated one. since writes are limited, the former is preferable, so we use the aux. & the rest of the code is just twiddly bits :-).

I was trying that earlier, It seemed like a sin to have to compile anything twice, but it might be the cleanest option.Again thank you for all of the help despite the fact that the lesson in this case might be that this is not the right job for LaTex.

@LongTime if sin it is, then the whole TeX world is guilty of it. having to compile twice is absolutely normal. usually, you have to compile rather more than that to get everything resolved. you don't get cross-references, citations, an index or a glossary on the first run. in some cases, you do not get pictures or correctly aligned columns in tables or notes in the correct places. usually, you don't get a bibliography either - nor do you get correct hyperlinks in many cases. so if you think having to compile twice or thrice or more is a sin, TeX will condemn you to perpetual penance ;).

@LongTime I am guessing either you are very, very new to LaTeX or you've been using an editor which hides details of compilation from you. for example, if you use overleaf, you might not realise that it is likely compiling your document several times.
